# How do I get the achemso package to include the DOIs?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib, doi, achemso

I'm using `achemso` to compile my references and I would like to include the DOIs.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%References - achemso is ACS style, it uses natbib
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}


\begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{achemso}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

and my `References.bib` look like:

```
@Article{Timmins2018,
  author    = {Amy Timmins and Nicholas J. Fowler and Jim Warwicker and Grit D. Straganz and Sam P. de Visser},
  title     = {Does Substrate Positioning Affect the Selectivity and     
Reactivity in the Hectochlorin Biosynthesis Halogenase?},
  journal   = {Frontiers in Chemistry},
  year      = {2018},
  volume    = {6},
  number    = {513},
  month     = {oct},
  doi       = {10.3389/fchem.2018.00513},
  publisher = {Frontiers Media {SA}},
}
```

I've tried:

```
\setkeys{acs}{doi = true}
```

also,

```
\setkeys{acs}{doi = true}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doi}{%
  \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \doi@aux
}
\makeatother
```

I get error messages when I try these

```
Package keyval Error: doi undefined. \setkeys{acs}{doi = true}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you used class `scrartcl` in your code. That class does not know command `\setkeys{acs}{doi = true}`.

Load class `achemso` instead of `scrartcl`.

Please see the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Timmins2018,
  author    = {Amy Timmins and Nicholas J. Fowler and Jim Warwicker and Grit D. Straganz and Sam P. de Visser},
  title     = {Does Substrate Positioning Affect the Selectivity and     
Reactivity in the Hectochlorin Biosynthesis Halogenase?},
  journal   = {Frontiers in Chemistry},
  year      = {2018},
  volume    = {6},
  number    = {513},
  month     = {oct},
  doi       = {10.3389/fchem.2018.00513},
  publisher = {Frontiers Media {SA}},
}
\end{filecontents}


%\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso} % <==========
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%References - achemso is ACS style, it uses natbib
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,super]{natbib}
\setkeys{acs}{doi = true} % <===========================================

\title{test}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{achemso} % <========================================
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting bibliography:

[image]